# How to make music?

Tags: software-recommendation, music

Do you know how I can produce my own songs on Ubuntu (11.04). Something like Fruity Loops oder Magix Music Maker on Windows, just for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

Some software available for ubuntu are Ardour, Audacity, ubuntu-studio LMMS and hydrogen
[Making Music on Ubuntu Linux](http://crab.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/making-music-on-ubuntu-linux/)
[Making Music(Beats) on Linux/Ubuntu with Hydrogen](http://www.linuxondesktop.in/2008/06/making-musicbeats-on-linuxubuntu-with.html)
LMMS is something like Fruity Loops. also ubuntu studio is good.

Hope this helped.Go on make some MUSIC!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing as easy as **FL Studio** in linux. but if you combine some of the applications, you can have pretty much same advantages.

try:

- **LMMS/Guitarix/zynaddsubfx** for creating music tracks.
- **Hydrogen** for creating Drum loops
- **Ardour** for Mixing
- **Jack** for connecting all these together

These tools are very much powerful specially *Ardour* is a mature project. pretty much replaces *Fl studio* for me.

you can find many good video tutorial in **Youtube** to start up.

Happy music making.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LMMS for music. For drumbeats, I'd recommend Hydrogen.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this great blog listing of [music software](http://ubuntu-music.org/blog/?page_id=25) for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into software center and install the newest version of Wine, you can install FL Studios 10 and 11. During the installation skip installing asio drivers. I use FL Studio 10 on Ubuntu 12.04 w/Wine.